# Debugging a custom find-function

Tags: elisp

Emacs is freezing when running the following custom find-function and I'm looking for some assistance, please, to debug it.

I'd like the prefix argument `C-u` to make the difference between `switch-to-buffer-other-window` or `switch-to-buffer`.  By removing `find-function-read` from the interactive statement, that function no longer returns a symbol -- so that is why I am using `make-symbol`.  I did not see an example by Googling that shows how to use an interactive command of `"P"` and another function such as `find-function-read` all in the same interactive statement.

```
(defun my-find-function (arg)
  "Find, in another window, the definition of FUNCTION near point.
See `find-function' for more details."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((function (make-symbol (format "%s" (car (find-function-read))))))
    (if (eq arg '(4))
      (find-function-do-it function nil 'switch-to-buffer-other-window)
      (find-function-do-it function nil 'switch-to-buffer))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
(defun my-find-function (arg)
  "Find, in another window, the definition of FUNCTION near point.
See `find-function' for more details."
  (interactive "p")
  (let* ((thing (thing-at-point 'symbol))
         (function
          (when thing (intern thing))))
    (if (eq arg 4)
      (find-function-do-it function nil 'switch-to-buffer-other-window)
      (find-function-do-it function nil 'switch-to-buffer))))
```

Note that `eq` is for numbers and symbols only, not for lists.
You can't do this:

```
(setq x '(1))
(eq x '(1))
;=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you -- using `make-symbol` instead of `intern` is what was making Emacs freeze, and you also hit the nail on the head with needing to use `eq` with `4`, or `equal` with `'(4)`.  Your help is greatly appreciated -- the freezing issues always perplex me because there are no hints to help me debug.

Comment: @lawlist for completeness, make-symbol returns a new uninterned symbol, so find-function would never find it anywhere.

Comment: 1. If the prefix arg is used only for a binary choice, I'd suggest using the raw arg (`"P"` instead of `"p"`) and then testing for `nil` vs non-`nil`. To me, that makes for clearer code (but that's the only advantage, and it's not important). 2. The doc string info about other window applies only with a prefix arg. 3. `FUNCTION` will be `nil` if there is no symbol at point. That will raise the error `You didn't specify a symbol`. Is that what you want?